# SDL_RenderCopy to set location

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl2

I'm coding a game's GUI in SDL2 and c++, I'm using SDL_RenderCopy to load the buttons on to the screen, but don't know how to get buttons in specific spots eg. bottom left corner, slightly below center. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually calculate the positions.

Positioning itself in SDL happens using destination rects. `SDL_RenderCopy` takes in a destination rectangle that you can use to scale and translate what you render.

Finding out the correct position is just a matter of math. For centering, you want to render at `(windowWidth / 2.0f - buttonWidth / 2.0f, windowHeight / 2.0f - buttonHeight / 2.0f)`. Simply offset the Y coordinate if you need to render a button just below. For bottom-left, set the X coordinate to 0, and don't divide the window height.